# Snowflake: Does a micro-partition change if I drop / add a column to a table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a process whereby a column could be added/removed to a staging table and I want to automatically update the subsequent SSOT (single source of truth) table with the schema change.
As such, I also want to take a backup of the table by using the Zero Copy Clone functionality in Snowflake.

My question is, if I take a clone of the SSOT table and then drop/add a column, will the underlying micro partitions see that as a data change or will the micro-partitions stay the same until that column is updated for a specific row?

My initial thought is no, the partitions wouldn't change because the data is stored in columnar structure. But was hoping for either someone that's tested this previously or knows the backend of snowflake very well to give me a definitive answer.

Haven't tested this yet but if I don't get an answer soon I probably will test.

Comment: This is covered in the Snowflake documentation. Look for the "DROP COLUMN" section on this page: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table

Comment: Thanks! What about adding a column?

Comment: If you just add a column but don't populate it there is no data change and so there cannot be any changes to micro-partitions